# SQL Markup and CSV Formatting in LaTeX

Tags: tables, programming, database

I have had a quick look for similar questions but I couldn't find anything, so apologies if this is a duplicate.

Firstly, I am looking for a way to grab information from external source files (i.e. `query1.sql`) which will then be formatted with language-specific highlighting (SQL in this case).

Secondly, I would like to grab information from an external csv file and have it formatted into a table.

I am using external files so that they can be updated automatically by an Automated Build process so that we have documentation that is always up to date.

As an example, I am looking for something like this:

Using the below script:

```
select *
from table;
```

We receive the output:

```
1 | 2 | 3
_________
a | b | c
d | e | f
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. The [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package can input external files and format them. It already has language definitions for SQL source.
2. The [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package can read CSV files so that they can be used in tables.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Alan, that is just what I was after.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I can't vote up on this account. :(

Comment: Besides `datatool`, there're also `pgfplotstable` and `csvsimple`.

Comment: @Leo Liu Thanks Leo, I'll take a look into those as well :)

Comment: @Leo It's a shame that the documentation for `csvsimple` is only in German. (Although one can probably figure most things out from the examples.)